# JUnit Test Suite: Way to create a dataset first before tests start running

Tags: java, maven, junit

I want to setup data for my entire test suite before any of the tests start running. I understand maven runs the test one by one and not a suite, so I cannot use @SuiteClasses. Also I dont want to create the dataset through dbunit-maven-plugin, the dataset has to be created over REST. Is there a way where I can run specific classes as part of maven pre-integration-test and post-integration-test to setup and clean?

For example

```
public class TestInit
{
    public void setUp()
    {
       //Data setup
    }

    public void tearDown()
    {
       //Data clean up
    }
}
```

make setup run before test suite starts and tearDown after it ends. Or can I run 2 separate classes like, TestInitSetup and TestInitTearDown?

Comment: why do you not want to use dbunit, can you give me some explanation ?

Comment: I have lot of data to seed and it is cumbersome to do so by providing a xml dataset. I have REST resource end points that takes in a fairly simple json payload and inserts data into the database. It is just a matter of convenience.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/mikinw/DataSet) is a Rule based solution. It may be useful.

The syntax looks like this:

```
public class SimpleWayToUseDataSetTest {
    @Rule
    public DataSetRule rule = new DataSetRule(); // <-- this is used to access to the testVectors from inside the tests

    public static class MyDataSet extends SimpleTestVectors {
        @Override
        protected Object[][] generateTestVectors() {
            return new Object[][] {
                    {true,  "alpha", new CustomProductionClass()}, // <-- this is a testVector
                    {true,  "bravo", new CustomProductionClass()},
                    {false, "alpha", new CustomProductionClass()},
                    {false, "bravo", new CustomProductionClass() }
            };
        }
    }

    @Test
    @DataSet(testData = MyDataSet.class) // <-- annotate the test with the dataset
    public void testFirst() throws InvalidDataSetException { // <-- any access to testData may result in Exception
        boolean myTextFixture = rule.getBoolean(0); // <-- this is how you access an element of the testVector. Indexing starts with 0
        String myAssertMessage = rule.getString(1); // <-- there are a couple of typed parameter getters
        CustomProductionClass myCustomObject = (CustomProductionClass) rule.getParameter(2); // <-- for other classes you need to cast
        Assert.assertTrue(myAssertMessage, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find a solution in JUnit, TestNG supports @BeforeSuite and @AfterSuite, which seem to do what you want.